# React-router-dom NavLink not rendering but goes to path

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

My problem today is that I am using react-router-dom and have all my paths set in AppRouter.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Landing } from '../components/Landing';
import About from '../components/About';
import { Resume } from '../components/Resume';
import { Phone } from '../components/Phone';
import { Github } from '../components/Github';


export class AppRouter extends Component {
   render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>          
              <Switch>
                  <Route exact path='/' Component={Landing}/>
                  <Route path='/about' Component={About} />
                  <Route path='/resume' Component={Resume} />
                  <Route path='/phone' Component={Phone} />
                  <Route path='/github' Component={Github} />
              </Switch>

        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

export default AppRouter
```

Now when I use NavLink in my NavBar component the URL does change to the paths but does not render the component to the screen.

NavBar component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

export class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">"IMAGE PLACE HOLDER" 
   </a>
                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data- 
toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria- 
controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle 
navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" 
id="navbarNavDropdown">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav">
                    <li className="nav-item active">
                        <NavLink className='nav-link' to='/'>Home</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a className="nav-link" href="#">Resume</a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <NavLink className='nav-link' 
to='/about'>About</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" 
id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria- 
haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Contact
                        </a>
                        <div className="dropdown-menu" aria- 
labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Phone</a>
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Email</a>
                        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Github</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Navbar
```

AppRouter -> Landing -> NavBar & Header

NavBar is not a direct child of AppRouter but descends from Landing. However, I did change it to where to NavBar is a direct child of AppRouter, but that did not change the fact that the Landing component is not rendering on initial load of the page.

Comment: Where is your `NavBar` component? The `NavLink` components have to be children to the `BrowserRouter` component as well to work.

Comment: My recommendation is to try wrapping your app in your index.js in the root of your project rather than wrapping it here. That may be a fix. Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: @Tholle So I went ahead and gave that a shot, but no luck. Did rrd change recently? Because I remember using this same format for a previous project and it worked out okay.

Comment: @JacobBralish Unfortunately it did not work out.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case anyone else is struggling with this issue. 
In my case, the app was wrapper with `<BrowserRouter>` at the top level and once more at a lower level (next to the NavLinks). Removing the second BrowserRouter solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when upgrading react to 17.x and react-router-dom to 5.x.
I fixed it by changing the `<Router>` wrapper by the `<BrowserRouter>`.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am faced with the same issue for react version 18.x and react-router-dom 5.x . I fixed this issue changing by index.js file. Wrapper by the `<BrowserRouter>`. and remove it `<React.StrictMode>`

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put BrowserRouter in place of React.strictmode

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './App';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>
    
  
);
```